# what's the difference between jsr354-api and jsr354-ri

Tags: java, java-money

I want to use a javamoney lib, I found two lib the below:
javamoney/jsr354-api and javamoney/jsr354-ri in the github. What's the diffirence, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ri in [jsr354-ri](https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-ri) stands for reference implementation, and api in 
[jsr354-api](https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-api) stands for the programming interface without the implementation.

You'd use api to program against and implementation is needed runtime to actually execute your code. Reference implementation means it's the "official" implementation version.

Comment: Thanks. You mean the api just interface and ri stands for implementation. So if I just used ri, Maybe the ri dependency the api.

Comment: @user3172755 yes. though recommended way would be to depend on api only, and then depend on the implementation only at runtime